# Tool for Software Development in Cloud

Tags: windows, linux, software-development

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question, so please suggest a different forum which better suits my question.

I am looking for software/cloud/browser application to develop software (python) in the cloud. What I want to do is to write (and test) code on Windows, check it in (to the cloud), then check it out again on a Linux computer, continue developing etc.

Is there a free tool/software/browser-based development tool that allows to work on the same python project using Windows and Linux computers?

Comment: Sure. It's called [distributed revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control). [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) would be a good example here. You have your code "in the cloud" (i.e. on some server connected to the net), and on your computer you use whatever IDE/SDK/… you prefer. If you want a recommendation for such, you'd need to specify what features you wish covered. Start reading the linked Wikipedia articles – you might even end up using Git (it's great and would be my first choice here), and not even need to ask :)

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks for the input, and I also know git. But what I need is a server or service to which I can do 'commits' from either Linux or Windows. I also do not need any features as the project is a one-man project (just myself working either from Linux or Windows...).

Comment: "what I need is a server or service to which I can do 'commits' from either Linux or Windows" – Git? What I'm missing here? You can [setup your own Git server](https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) (if you have a server on the net), or use one of the many services like Github to host your "remote repo". Also see: [How To Set Up GitLab As Your Very Own Private GitHub](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gitlab-as-your-very-own-private-github-clone).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you [**Koding**](https://koding.com).

What is Koding?

> **Koding** is a developer community and cloud development environment where developers come together and code in the browser – with a real development server to run their code. ([source](https://koding.com/About))

Koding is **web-based development**, so you can access that through browser. You will be given a virtual machine in the cloud where runs on Ubuntu OS. Koding not only supports **Python** but also another programming languages. If you want to know more what the features will you get, you may check it out [here](https://koding.com/Features).

The sum up, you will be given:

- Virtual Machine
- IDE
- Community

I hope this answer is what you need. But, I feel something is missing here, though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [Cloud9](http://www.c9.io)

Its a online feature filled IDE that combines simplicity with the power of an Ubuntu Distro. The IDE basically runs on an ubuntu setup throuh cloud and no install is required.

You can also run any of the commands of terminal as it is like a virtual machine at your fingertips.

It supports more than 40 languages and is accessible from anywhere through a browser, so you can switch the OS and do whatever you like in the IDE (well a decent browser is required though).

Here's a screenshot of the IDE it looks pretty much like sublime.

[image]

And yeah You can code simultaneously with peers live!!

Comment: I am currently trying Cloud9 and it seems to be exactly what I wanted!!