# Specific IDE for "Design on the browser"

Tags: web-development, ide, cloud-service

Recently, I'm reading a lot about ["Design in the browser"](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/my-thoughts-on-designing-in-the-browser-vs-designing-in-photoshop--cms-23405), but I didn't find yet a good web-based IDE that could help in this "new approach" (if exists).

I'm looking for a web-based IDE with some specific requirements like:

> - HTML editor (also Markdown support);
> - Javascript editor with auto-complete;
> - CSS editor (transpiler for Saas is a plus);
> - Integrated Tools that helps with CSS like [colors](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and [CSS3](http://css3generator.com/)
> - Live preview of the page (I am creating in the browser, then it would be 
>     nice to see the live results);
> - Integration with GitHub;
> - Simple image editor;
> - WYSIWYG function for sketch pages;
> - Integrated Typograph tools (like [it](http://www.gridlover.net/app/)) and fonts source;

I want to do all development on-line in a integrated environment. I'm thinking about something like a super-[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that works effectively as an IDE, with tabs to each function (HTML, CSS, etc...) or something like that.

I already know the [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/) and looks like a good option, but I was not totally satisfied because it does not seem entirely appropriate for "Design in the browser" approach and am looking for other options.

Paid and free options are welcome.

Comment: Similar questions about web authoring tools have already been posted. Can you describe how your Question is different?

Comment: I'm looking for a IDE focused on the design part that helps the developer to create the page itself, before the logical, but also helps with logic as any common IDE. I tried to update the requirements to improve the question.

Comment: @BasilBourque. Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but the only [similar question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20043/tool-for-software-development-in-cloud) that I found is not focused in the design part, but in the code